# Is it possible to shorten this javascript-code I wrote

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some code of javascript for an online-shop, but in the noob-way...

```
$('div[id^="optionen"] div.wert:nth-child(1) input#format').on("change", function() {
    //alert('123');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander').addClass('hidden').css('display','none');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(1)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(2)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(3)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(4)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(5)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(6)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(7)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(8)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(9)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(10)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(11)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(12)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(13)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
}); 

$('div[id^="optionen"] div.wert:nth-child(2) input#format').on("change", function() {
    //alert('123');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander').addClass('hidden').css('display','none');    
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(1)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(14)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(15)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(16)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(17)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(18)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(19)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(20)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(21)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(22)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(23)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(24)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(25)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
});
```

There are four more functions for four further inputs, where only the value of the nth-child differs.

I believe it's possible to shorten this code? Can someone tell me how?

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Can you give these divs a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into the options for the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) pseudo-class. You can target the first 13 children with `:nth-child(-n+13)`.

```
$('div[id^="optionen"] div.wert:nth-child(1) input#format').on("change", function() {
  $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander')
    .addClass('hidden')
    .css('display','none');
  $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(-n+13)')
    .removeClass('hidden')
    .css('display','block')
});
```

To get 14 through 25, you'd use `:nth-of-type(n+14):nth-of-type(-n+25)`

Comment: this looks very good as well! another way to shorten my code...thank you!

Comment: thank you again canon! gonna take this then as the accepted answer!

Comment: but one more question...how am I able to target the children 14 - 25 for the next function on "div.wert:nth-child(2)"?

Comment: yeah, this works! but I ran into another little problem...I need the first _nth-child to be shown each time, too. tried it like this: `$(wert + ':nth-child(2) input#format').on("change", function() {
 hide($(exp));
 show($(exp + ':nth-child(1)'));
 show($('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(-n+14)'));
});`...but this didn't work...gonna try on...

Comment: thx for your reply again canon! sorry for my late response, had a hdd crash and it took my until now to re-set up my system...but stupid question of me...i should have known that...thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You may simply loop over the items you want to change

```
$('div[id^="optionen"] div.wert:nth-child(1) input#format').on("change", function() {
    $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander').addClass('hidden').css('display','none');

    for (var i=1;i<=13;i++) {
        $('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(' + i + ')').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
    }
});
```

Comment: this one already helped me to save a lot of lines, thank you!

Comment: Creating new jQuery objects for each of the 13 items seems needlessly heavy.

Answer (score 2):

This code should do exact same than what You posted.

```
var wert = 'div[id^="optionen"] div.wert'; 
var exp = 'div[id^="optionen"] div.expander';

$(wert + ":nth-child(1) input#format").on("change", function() {
   hide($(exp));
   for(var i=1;i<=13;i++) {
      show($(exp + ":nth-child("+i+")"));
   }
}

$(wert + ":nth-child(2) input#format").on("change", function() {
   hide($(exp));

   show($(exp + ":nth-child(1)"));
   for(var i=14;i<=25;i++) {
      show($(exp + ":nth-child("+i+")"));
   }
}

// FUNTIONS TO HIDE AND SHOW LIKE YOU WANT IT
function show(ctx) {
   ctx.addClass("hidden").css("display", "none");
}

function hide(ctx) {
   ctx.removeClass("hidden").css("display", "block");
}
```

Comment: You should avoid to use same long strings many times and also those HIDE/SHOW functions will help a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to my mind is to iterate through this:

```
$('div[id^="optionen"] div.expander:nth-child(**X**)').removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
```

Since X is the only thing changing here from 1 to 25.

But, I'm sure you can just create a better [selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and this all of this in one line. Show us your HTML so we can try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Short and general answer: get an array of the jquery objects you want to mutate, `divs`, possibly using a selector with a common class on those divs, or using `.children()` from the parent element, however makes most sense, then:

```
divs.forEach(function(div) {
   div.removeClass('hidden').css('display','block');
)};
```